# Response Time on a web page like a stop watch

Tags: web, performance-testing, web-testing, response-time

I have searched and found so many answers but nothing that fits my requirement. I will try to explain here and see if any of you guys have some tips.

- I wish to click on a link manually and from there on; I wish that some kind of tool or service starts recording time from my click and stops when the desired page is loaded. This way, I am able to find out the exact user interface response time.
- All the online web testing services ask for main URL. In my case the main URL has gazillion links and I wish to use only 1 link as standard sample which is a dynamic link

For example:
- I click on my friend's name on Facebook
- From my click to the time page is loaded, if there's a tool that does the stop watch thing?

End goal is:

I will be stress testing a server with extensive load and client wishes to see response time of simple random pages when load is at 500, 1000, 2000 and so on.

Please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http Watch and Fiddler helped. Didn't really go as I had thought but pretty Close and satsifactory. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple load tester tool and the developer tools on the Chrome browser, you can get a clear picture of page load times under load. Also you can see which request completed in how much time and the time from start to finish.
Just start the load test and try from the chrome.
Also you can use a automated latency monitor like smokeping.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [httpwatch](https://www.httpwatch.com/) or [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) to find the client side page load times.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [WPT](http://webpagetest.org/) this is a tool which has a private and a public instance for serving exactly what you want to do also supports [scripted](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/using-webpagetest/scripting) steps executed via the browsers JS the nicest thing i find in WPT is that you can use the public instance to measure the actual user experience from other than yours world locations or you can make a private one.